# Where did ServiceStack 3.9.59 come from?

Tags: servicestack

On [NuGet.org](http://www.nuget.org/packages/ServiceStack/) I see 3.9.59 available (as of yesterday) but this does not appear to be in the ServiceStack [GitHub repo](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack), which only shows 3.9.58. I expect this is a short-lived question, but I was assuming any new versions would show up in GitHub first before being available through NuGet. (I had gone to GitHub to see what changed in 3.9.59 once I saw there was a new version.)

Comment: Apparently your assumption was incorrect.

Comment: Clearly it was. I'm most interested in knowing what has changed in this version (and would have otherwise used GitHub to find out), but am also still curious about what the package publishing process is if not from GitHub source.

Comment: If there's no code changes but a version number bump, it probably means that somebody botched packaging the release somehow.

Comment: Yeah, it must have just been packaged from a local repo (mythz's?). All the nuspec files on GitHub still say 3.9.58. So it's hard to know whether there were any code changes.

Comment: Demis mentioned 3.9.59 in a [recent Google+ post](https://plus.google.com/app/basic/stream/z12tfvoackvnx1xzd04cfrirpvybu1nje54), but didn't say what was included in that release.

Comment: Wow, ok. So my question of whence came 3.9.59 is almost moot in light of the rest of his post. So ServiceStack is going commercial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 3.9.59 release is now [visible on GitHub](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/commit/5b1891ec50493f7c20a1cedb3ce71a00e0dbb4e2), so you should be able to infer what's incuded in that release by checking the commits preceeding that.

Apparently it was just pushed to NuGet before the nuspec/AssemblyInfo.cs changes made it to GitHub.